# Group By List<Item>

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have this class:

```
public class Item 
{
    public virtual int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Previa Previa { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

And now i need to a query to find every Items in database, group by Products, with the sum of Quantity and Total.
For find every Items, i use:

```
public List<Item> FindItem(int IdProduct = 0)
{
    var retorno = (from c in Session.Query<Item>()
                   select c);

    if (IdProduto > 0)
        retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.Product.Id == IdProduct)

    return retorno.ToList<Item>();
}
```

But I don't know how to group these items. Could someone please help me?

Comment: What is `grupo`? Where did that come from? What do you mean by group these items - how do you mean?

Comment: Are there many products with the same `IdProduct` ?

Comment: Oded, sorry..."grupo" in the reality is "retorno". I edit.

Comment: L.B.: No, every product have one unique id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is far from clear, but it *sounds* like you want a query such as:

```
var query = from item in Session.Query<Item>()
            group item by item.Product into g
            select new {
                Product = g.Key,
                Quantity = g.Sum(item => item.Quantity),
                Total = g.Sum(item => item.Total)
            };
```

How you then pass that back is a different matter - you almost certainly *don't* want a `List<Item>` though...

Comment: Thanks, is a very good solution, but now how i manipulate this ? This return a List<object> ? If yes, how i get every field in list ?

Comment: @JohnyMoraes: That's why I said "How you then pass that back is a different matter" - you probably want to create a new type for *just* this grouping.