# how to retrieve common items from List C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, list

I want to retrieve common element from list and want to show in below format.

I have a `List<Property>`, the `Property` class is as follows:

```
public class Property 
{
    public Property(){}
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Value of list are as below:

```
Name   Value
---------------
Sam -->  1

Sam -->  2

Sam -->  5

mike --> 2

mike --> 3
```

**Expected result**

I wanted to display common items with comma separated values as shown below:

```
Name       Value
-------------------
Sam  -->  1, 2, 5 

mike -->  2, 3
```

Comment: If you have tried any code, Do post it .

Comment: Take a look at GroupBy LINQ method.

Comment: related: [Grouping objects by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447648/grouping-objects-by-property-value), [Group By List<Item>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141030/group-by-listitem), [Group By Multiple Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns), [C# List<> GroupBy 2 Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363655/c-sharp-list-groupby-2-values), [C# List - Group By - Without Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460309/c-sharp-list-group-by-without-linq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of `GroupBy` and `string.Join` could do:

```
List<Property> list = new List<Property>();
var result = list.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                .Select(r => new 
                        { 
                            Name = r.Key, 
                            Values = string.Join(",", r.Select(t => t.Value)) 
                        });
```